# Load page via PHP vs AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, user-experience

In my dynamic website I first load the `index.html` page as a `document structure` and then I make some request to the `PHP server` via `ajax` and insert the data to the page. Is this better than loading all the contents via PHP (`index.php`) only? Which method is faster?

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my understanding:

`index.html`

Step 1: Server sends html page to client.
Step 2: AJAX request is made to the server.
Step 3: Server processes the data.
Step 4: Server responds to the client.
Step 5: Client-side JavaScript changes the page based on the response.

`index.php`

Step 1: Server processes PHP and sends html page.
Step 2: ?????
Step 3: Profit.

EDIT:
This was assuming that the same amount of PHP code has to be executed either way.  View [Ravi Dasari's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1225168/ravi-dasari) answer for a better description.

Comment: This answer may sound simple but it is not accurate. Why do you think people use AJAX if .php is always faster? Please refer to my answer below for details.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have a good reason not to, just loading index.php is likely smarter. This way, only one call is made to the server, and it handles putting the data together. The other way, you make a call to the server for the index page, and then another call for the data, and then you make the client put the data together. It's not necessarily wrong to do this, but it's probably the wrong choice in most scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

First to set expectation both are at the end HTML code that will come to browser for rendering. So it all depends on the amount of data you need to fetch and the time required to fetch it in order to show this page.

Approach 1: Loading index.php
Load time varies based on what kind of data you want to show here.

1. If you have some DB operations and it is different for every user then this php page will take a while to get all the information and give it to browser.
2. If you do not have any user specific DB operation or rendering then you can go ahead with .php approach since your server will generate this HTML once and cache it. So you get a better load time.
3. This approach will have less number of HTTP requests so loads faster provided PHP->HTML is fast.

Approach 2: Loading index.html
Your current loading approach is very quick in terms of page load but user still have to wait for the full content. But at least he saw the first landing content and see some spinner and will wait for the content.

Imagine if it is a .php and loading user specific content is slow, then user may not wait till the page is loaded and he will not like it.

So both the approaches are suitable for different situation.

Also you should optimize your page load time in otherways. You may want to check how many HTTP request are being made from your page to the server in total. You can check more details in below blog.
[How to improve you page load time](https://dasariravi.wordpress.com/2015/08/12/performance-improvements/)

Comment: when page loads I make a max of 2 or 3 ajax requests.

Comment: you should also consider how many HTTP request(all js, css and images and AJAX calls) being made from the browser. You can check this in browser developer tool -> Network tab. (Makesure you see all HTTP request, not just AJAX or JS files)

Comment: there is a font a min.js and a min.css, thats all

Comment: Then you have very few resources you need to fetch and it is good.

Comment: @rexhin you still have doubts after reading my post above?

Comment: Yes I do not now what to choose.

Comment: okay bro, I assume you have already implanted index.html approach and you still seem to have time, so go ahead with implementing .php approach as well. And then test the load times from the browser and consider the user experience aspects. Since you are new to these things one best way is to do it yourself and see what is correct for your situation.

Comment: yes i'm going to test them both

Answer (score 1):

Basically using ajax method for data purpose on loaded page is could good and bad in different scenarios if we are concern about speed, then we should populate the data on the first server request, because if we are sending request to the server multiple times defiantly it will affect the bandwidth. But if we are using any kind of listing on page then we can use datatables also in a normal structured html page having an ajax request to get records from server. Here is one more benefit of using ajax method that if we have to make REST api's for the same listing or data the same action will work here like api. That why these ajax calling are in trend z.